# Google Search Console says 5xx error, but won't show page URLs

Tags: google-search-console, http-code-500

I can fix the 5xx error if I know what page, and I thought Search Console was supposed to show page URLs? But this is what my page shows and I can't see any URLs to troubleshoot further...

[image]

I suppose maybe it's because the issue has been resolved? Like there are no current examples, but then does it store the previously affected websites that are clearly there on the graph somewhere that I can find? Or basically is there just nothing I can do in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

'5xx' are basically server errors.  This means that Google can't read any of your pages.  If it is sporadic, then your hosting company is not up to scratch.

If it is happening permanently, then you have a problem on your site that returns an error to Google.  Try checking your website

1. With different browsers (after clearing the cache on them)
2. With online tools.

Comment: yes i understand this, but my question is more, when Google doenst' list the URL why is that?

Comment: @james, I think Rohit's point is that a 50x error isn't about any specific page.  Generally, the issue is that Google is getting the error before it ever reaches a web pages.   I.e., the server chokes on something (a configuration, an api call, a web service extention,, etc). This may be sporadic, but you might try looking in your web server logs for the error to see if it gives you any more information.